# How do you read cookie values in ColdFusion that have special characters in the name?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion

I'm working with ColdFusion trying to read the value stored in a session cookie named "LiSESSION:test-0".  The cookie is stored in the "test.com" domain, from code ran from "community.test.com" and I don't have access to the code to change the name.  I am reading the value from "test.com" which is how I am able to access the cookie.

For example:

```
<cfparam name="cookie.LiSESSIONID:test-0" type="string" default="" />
```

.. raises an error saying that ":" is an invalid character ("Invalid parser construct").

Comment: It looks like you can accomplish this by using CGI.HTTP_COOKIE, but would like to make sure I'm using the proper method.  Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same way you do it with all variables (not just cookies) - by using bracket notation:

```
Cookie['LiSESSIONID:test-0']
```